# How programmatically set locksreen owner info message in Android?

Tags: android

Is this possible to programmatically set in Android locksreen owner info?
By owner info I mean "Alex Dobie" in photo below:

[image]

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

if someone is interested in the solution:
it's not writable as it's in settings.secure, but readable with

`Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCK_SCREEN_OWNER_INFO);`